# B2C iPad with keyboard MFA

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

When we use an iPad with attached keyboard we cannot get passed the phone code page. We can enter the code but after inserted them all nothing happens.

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: What code? It's the default azure b2c mfa login page. Can't change anything about that.

Comment: We verified against iPad Pro 11 & 10.3 - Safari & Chrome - Real devices and it is working fine. What is your type of iPad and which browser?

Comment: Just standard safari. Did you use an attached keyboard? Because without it works fine